# Convert string to datetime and remove the time part from the date

Tags: c#

I have a date returned from database which includes even the time. i want to remove the time part of the string and send only the date. my code is as given below

```
DateTime Var = new DateTime();
      Var = Convert.ToDateTime(Dset.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Date"]);
      Var = Var.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Do not use variable names that are so easily confused with language keywords

Comment: And avoid parsing strings anyway - if you use an appropriate data type in your database, you shouldn't need `Convert.ToDateTime`... you should just be able to cast.

Comment: Additionally, you've provided code (yay!) but given *no indication* of what happens when you try that code. I suspect it doesn't compile because you're trying to assign a `String` value to a `DateTime` variable, but you should provide that information yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime Var = Convert.ToDateTime(Dset.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Date"]).Date; //only date part
string date = Var.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 3):

it will store only date in `DateTime` object

```
Var = Var.Date;
```

time will be 00:00:00

or you can store it as string:

```
var dateString = Var.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can custom your date string format by using `DateTime.ToSting("your format")` method.
then the code will be like this.

```
  DateTime Var = new DateTime();
  Var = Convert.ToDateTime(Dset.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Date"]);
  Var = Var.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

you can also use `SubString()` method to gain the date part of the datetime string.